# How do I make a column in a Microsoft SharePoint an auto-incrementing identifier that the user can not edit?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, column, administration

How do I make a column in a Microsoft SharePoint an auto-incrementing identifier that the user can not edit?

I want it such that an ID field is incremented automatically when a user enters a new row into a SharePoint list and I want this ID column to be the primary key AKA the "Title" column of the list.

Answer (score 1):

As you have tagged this question with [`list`](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/list) tag, I will assume that you are using a SharePoint list and you want an auto-incremented column in your "list".

By default SharePoint provides an `ID` column in the lists which is an auto-incremented column. This ID field will be incremented automatically when a user adds a new item/row into a SharePoint list.

You can show this ID column in your list view by following these steps:

1. Go to your SharePoint list
2. Click on **Add column** and select **Show or hide columns**:

   [image]
3. Check the checkbox of `ID` column and click "Apply" to save the changes:

   [image]

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: Fort some reason, after I added the ID to be viewable from the List, it is an editable field when I click on the "+Add new item" button

Comment: ID is a SharePoint default column and it should "not" be editable from list forms. Can you attach the screenshot of add new item form if the ID field is editable?

Comment: Hi @xarzu, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept my above response as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. Thank you!

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.